# Xamarin forms Different Mac Address's

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms app.
I want to save mac address's, I could get mac address but its different when I check it from device's settings.

```
  public static string getMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;

        var all = Collections.List(Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);

        foreach (var interfaces in all)
        {
            if (!(interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).Name.Contains("wlan0")) continue;

            var macBytes = (interfaces as
            Java.Net.NetworkInterface).GetHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) continue;

            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in macBytes)
            {
                string convertedByte = string.Empty;
                convertedByte = (b & 0xFF).ToString("X2") + ":";

                if (convertedByte.Length == 1)
                {
                    convertedByte.Insert(0, "0");
                }
                sb.Append(convertedByte);
            }

            macAddress = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.Length - 1);


            Console.WriteLine($"Mac Address : {macAddress} ");
            return macAddress;

        }
        return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    }
```

This code returns me mac address like A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6 but my device's mac address is like G1:H2:I3:J4:K5:L6.

Why is that ? How can I match these mac address and devices. I'll use that app with our costumers, we need to know that.

My phone is poco f3 and android 12 works on it. Probably our costumer's devices have lower android versions.

Comment: Refer to this : https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-mac-randomization-behavior. Also if you are looking to find a way to identify device - user you could use the AndroidId.

Comment: I need to Identify device - user, yes. If I use AndroidID can i find it from settings of phone 
 easily? @NikosBasdanis

Comment: you could find it for android like this :
string androidId = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);

Comment: I find my device id but  I think I need user find his user id. How can user find his devices android id ? I mean when I want to find this device what should I do ? @NikosBasdanis

Comment: The user has not the capability to find the device's Android ID. An Android ID is a unique id that gets assigned to every Android device when it sets up. refer to this : https://prioridata.com/glossary/android-id/ .

Comment: @NikosBasdanis I find a way to get real mac address. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go settings, wifi, select connected wifi, you need to find privacy, change that random mac address to device mac address. Than you will see real mac address in application. [image]